# Why does File::bytes iterate over bytes in a different order than hexdump?

Tags: file, iterator, rust, byte, endianness

I'm trying to read some raw bytes of a file, so I looked at the docs and threw together a function which looks like it should read the bytes into a vector and read the 32-bit integer starting at the head.

```
fn filetobytes(name: &'static str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let file = File::open(name).expect("No such file");
    let filebytes: Vec<u8> = file.bytes().map(|readbyte| readbyte.unwrap()).collect();

    return filebytes;
}

fn parse_int(index: usize, vector: &Vec<u8>) -> u32 {
    let mut num: u32 = 0;
    for i in 0..4 {
        num = num << 8;
        num = num | ((vector[index + i] as u32) & 0xff);
        println!("Byte is {:x}", vector[index + i]);
    }
    return num;
}

fn main() {
    let filebytes = filetobytes("diddy.h");
    println!("0x{:x}", parse_int(0, &filebytes));
}
```

I then tried to move forward, but quickly discovered that none of my logic was working. After doing some sniffing, I found that I wasn't getting bytes in the order I expected. For instance, the above code (which prints the first four bytes separately then composited as an integer) produces the following output

```
Byte is 23
Byte is 64
Byte is 65
Byte is 66
0x23646566
```

If I do a `hexdump` on `diddy.h`, I get the following output.

```
0000000 6423 6665 6e69 2065 4944 4444 5f59 4957
0000010 5444 2048 3031 0a35 6423 6665 6e69 2065
0000020 4944 4444 5f59 4548 4749 5448 3120 3035
0000030 630a 6e6f 7473 7520 736e 6769 656e 2064
0000040 6873 726f 2074 6964 6464 5f79 6164 6174
0000050 315b 3735 3035 3b5d 000a               
0000059
```

Oddly enough, it seems that `vector[0]` accesses byte 1, `vector[1]` accesses byte 0, `vector[2]` gets byte 3, `vector[3]` gets byte 2, and so on.

What could I have possibly done to cause this behavior, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try `hexdump -C`

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 If you answer your own question, could you do it as an answer so you can mark it as resolved?

Comment: Yes, please remove the edited part and post it as an answer. It is [perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jan Zerebecki's comment is correct, but might benefit from a little elaboration:

Hexdump defaults to showing you the file as a collection of 16-bit integer values.  The reason they appear to be in the 'wrong order' is that Hexdump respects the endianness of the host computer, and you ran it on a little-endian machine.

Lets do an example using hexdump's custom output-format option.  First, we'll write an xxd-compatible hexdump, and convert it to binary.

```
$ echo 00000000: 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef > num.hex
$ xxd -r num.hex num.bin
```

Then we'll prove to ourselves that hexdump *can* read it using the canonical output mode:

```
$ hexdump -C num.bin
00000000  01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef                           |.#Eg....|
00000008
```

Next, we'll use it's rather obscure output-format option to show the values as hex, but choosing 1,2,4,and 8 bytes at a time:

```
$ hexdump -e '1/1 "%02x "' num.bin
01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef
$ hexdump -e '1/2 "%02x "' num.bin
2301 6745 ab89 efcd
$ hexdump -e '1/4 "%02x "' num.bin
67452301 efcdab89
$ hexdump -e '1/8 "%02x "' num.bin
efcdab8967452301
```

What you see is hexdump interpreting those bytes as little-endian integers of varying size, and performing the byte-swap required to place the most-significant-digit on the left...the way we like to represent numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `hexdump` was what was actually displaying in the wrong order. `hexdump -C` reads it correctly.

Comment: hexdump defaults to its `-x` option which displays every 2 bytes as one hexadecimal number.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the [`Bytes` create](https://crates.io/crates/bytes), you should be able to write your `parse_int` function as:

```
use bytes::{ByteOrder, BigEndian, LittleEndian};

fn parse_int(index: usize, vector: &[u8]) -> u32 {
    // BigEndian/Little Edian here should be determined by the file format, NOT the system format
    LittleEndian::read_u32(&vector[index])
}
```